# Opencart showing keys instead of values

Tags: php, arrays, key, opencart, decimal-point

I have a problem with opencart 2 site which is showing text from keys of asocciative arrays instead of its values.
For example it shows "decimal_point" instead of "."

I tried trough numerous ways to fix it like placing `$_['decimal_point']= '.';` in product/product.php but there is no result.
Weird is because on local WAMP windows is showing ok but on linux server is bad.
I was looking if folder has same name (case sensiitive) like setup in admin panel, but ... everything looks fine.

Look at the test site location *http://178.62.86.209/* for a problem.

It seems like something is wrong in loading language but cannot find what..

Comment: Can we get some code? Seeing the end result is helpful, but we can't divine the PHP from that.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved...
after days of searching for an answer i found a realy stupid error made in config file with wrong path to language folder
there was like /public_html/language/
instead of /public_html/catalog/language/

no idea how it happened
anyway @Phiter thank you very much for offer for help, greetings